# Uploading Python Django Project to GitHub

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, git, github

I am new in Django. My friend and I are starting to create projects to add them to our portfolio for job hunting purposes. I have a few questions for you - the professionals.

1. Exactly which folders should be present on GitHub when uploading Django projects?
2. Should folders like django_env, .idea, or files like .DS_Store and .gitignore be present there?
3. Where exactly should the requirements.txt and README.md files be located?

[image]

In general, how and what exactly should be uploaded to GitHub to present a project professionally?

Comment: You can look at some templates for `.gitignore` here: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore  You probably want to customize it a bit (some people commit some files in .idea others ignore the whole thing)

Comment: Virtual envs should not be in the repo, rather a script (e.g. bash) or an instruction in README.md how to recreate the env after pulling the project. .DS_Store has nothing to do with Django and is MacOS specific (not needed in the repo neither).

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/django,python

Answer (score 1):

1. The following folders should be present on GitHub when uploading Django projects:Django project folder, Apps folder, Staticfiles folder, Templates folder, Tests folder
2. No, folders like `django_env` and `.idea` should not be present on GitHub. These folders are used for local development and debugging, and they are not necessary for running your Django project on GitHub.
   The `.DS_Store` file is a hidden file created by macOS, and the `.gitignore`
   file is used to tell Git which files to ignore. These files can be present
   on GitHub, but they will not be tracked by Git.
3. The `requirements.txt` file and `README.md` file should be located in the root directory of your Django project.

Answer (score 1):

-> Folders/Files You Should NOT Commit to GitHub:

**'django_env':** This is your virtual environment. You should never commit a virtual environment to version control. It's large and contains binaries specific to your system. Instead, use a **'requirements.txt'** to specify dependencies.

**.idea:** This folder is generated by the JetBrains IDE (like PyCharm). It contains personal IDE configurations and shouldn't be in version control.

**.DS_Store:** This is a system file generated by macOS for its file system. You should exclude this.

You can use a **.gitignore file** to tell Git to exclude these files and folders.

**.gitignore:**

This should be at the root level of your project.
A typical Django **.gitignore** might look like this:

```
# Virtual Environment
```

django_env/

## JetBrains IDEs

.idea/

## macOS

.DS_Store

## SQLite (if you're using it as your database during development)

*.sqlite3

## Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files

**pycache**/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

## Files that might appear on external disk

.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes

**requirements.txt:**

This should be at the root level of your project.
Generate this using the command **pip freeze > requirements.txt** from within your virtual environment. This will list all installed packages with their versions. This helps others (and you) recreate the environment.

**README.md:**

This should also be at the root level of your project.
It's your project's main documentation entry point on GitHub. Include details about:
What the project is about.
How to set it up.
Dependencies.
How to run it.
Screenshots, if possible, to provide a visual insight.

**Other Files and Folders:**

All Django-specific folders like your apps, **manage.py**, templates, static, and media (if you have them) should be committed to GitHub.
Make sure you don't commit sensitive data like secret keys, passwords, or API keys. Use environment variables for sensitive data. Packages like **python-decouple** or **'django-environ'** can help manage environment variables and configurations safely.

**Professional Presentation:**

Provide a clear project structure. Use folders wisely to separate different parts of your application.
Write clean, commented, and readable code. This is especially important if potential employers are looking at your code.
Provide comprehensive documentation. Apart from the **README.md**, also consider adding a **CONTRIBUTING.md** (guidelines for others who want to contribute) or **LICENSE** (specifies the terms under which the project's software is made available).
Regular, clear commit messages show your progress and thought process.
If the project is large or has several components, consider using the "Projects" or "Issues" feature on GitHub to manage and document tasks, bugs, and features.